# How is Json based architecture called?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, single-page-application

We have a Single Page Application that communicates with a server via Json. It's not RESTFul since we do not use DELETE or any other methods other than Ajax POST. How is this type of architecture called?

For example:

```
POST {operation: 'getUser', input: {id: '2'}}
POST {operation: 'deleteUser', input: {id: '2'}}
POST {operation: 'addUser', input: {login: 'myLogin'}}
```

Comment: I may be wrong but a RESTful service doesn't have to include a DELETE method if it isn't necessary for the application.

Comment: _"How is this type of architecture called?"_ - Doesn't the term you already used, "Single Page Application", cover it? I don't see the fact that the data is transmitted in JSON format as particularly relevant when talking about the architecture - it could as easily be XML or some custom format, the point is you're (presumably) using Ajax and doing GET/POST http methods. (Given that you _do_ have a `deleteUser` operation, why aren't you doing that as a DELETE request?)

Comment: I would call it json-rpc (similar to xml-rpc).

I think you're correct when you say it's not restful as it does not appear to deal with resources.

Comment: I would call it an http service.

Comment: Perhaps the OP needs to clarify whether he means "how" or "what" is this called, you all seem to be getting a different question from me.

Answer (score 1):

It's still RESTful, you're just only using two of the HTTP methods (GET and POST).

How it's called is up to you. With Javascript, the most common method is with an AJAX request where you **can** specify the HTTP method (whether it be GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, etc).

Here's a [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) example to make a DELETE request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/api',
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: {
        pass: var1,
        etc: var2
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // Request successful, do something with result here
    }
});
```

**Edit:** here's an example of how to make those post requests you've just added:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/path/to/api/getUser',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        id: '2'
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // Successful request callback, do stuff
    }
});
```

I'd also suggest using `cache: false` as an option, since it defaults to true in this scenario - not ideal for an API request like that.

**Note:** from the manual:

> Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.